# How to add next option between the following images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<td>                                         
    <span class="preview">
        <a class="fancyOpen" title="Processed Image" href="'+o["files"][i].url+'">
            <img src="'+o["files"][i].thumbnail_url+'" />
        </a>       
        <a class="fancyOpen" title="Original Image" href="'+base_url+"files/upload?t=r&getfile="+o["files"][i].name+'">
            <img src="'+base_url+"files/upload?t=r&getthumb="+o["files"][i].name+'" />
        </a>       
    </span>                 
</td>
```

How to add next option between processed and original images?

Comment: Could clearify your question. Do you want to add it dynamicly with jQuery or in your static html file?

Comment: Can you put an example of what's the expected result and how are you trying to accomlish it? I don't really understand your question…

Comment: What is going on with `href="'+o["files"][i].url+'">`? Is this whole code part of big string?

Comment: i have to display two different type of image and above code works. But i want to add next option (symbolically >) on image to move form one image to next image.

Answer (score 1):

```
function before(node, insertNode){
    return node && insertNode && node.parentNode? 
        node.parentNode.insertBefore(insertNode, node): 
        false;
}

function after(node, insertNode){
    return node && insertNode && node.parentNode? 
        before(node.nextSibling, insertNode) || node.parentNode.appendChild(insertNode): 
        false;
}

after( document.querySelector('.fancyOption'), nextOption );
```

where nextOption has to be a Dom-Node